# Get UserControls dynamically via XamlReader.Load, IsLoaded is false at UI Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

I try to save and load TabItems via **XamlWriter** and **XamlReader** at runtime so that the user can restore the previous session. Each TabItem consists of UserControls and standard WPF controls like grids,buttons and checkboxes.
It all works fine until I try to subscribe to events of let's say a button.

If I raise them manually with *RaiseEvent()* they work, but if I click on them nothing happens. Even if I set **IsEnabled=false** the button is displayed as enabled. **LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode** gives me the right button, but the Click event also won't trigger. The IsLoaded property is false, so I assume there has to be some underlying problem with the initialization.

Basically this is the code to read from the file

```cs
StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(file);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sw);
TabItem tabItem = (TabItem)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

.. and this to save each TabItem to a seperate xml file

```cs
foreach (TabItem tabItem in tabControlMain.Items)
{
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path,tabItem.Name + ".xml"), false);
string savedTab = XamlWriter.Save(tabItem);
sw.Write(savedTab);
sw.Close();
 }
```

Here is an example TabItem saved to a file

```xml
<TabItem IsSelected="True" Header="Test" Name="tabItem1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:womoc="clr-namespace:WeldOsMqttOpcClient;assembly=blabla">
    <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <TextBox Margin="0,0,30,0" Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <womoc:UcOverviewTabPage Autoconnect="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid Name="gridParentOv">
                <Grid Name="gridMqttOpcControls" Height="599.08" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <womoc:UcConnection Name="ucOpc" MinWidth="400" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <GroupBox Header="OPC [10.5.51.130]" Name="groupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <Grid Name="gridTextBoxesWithValues" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Name="rowLabel" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Background="#FF008000" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="labelConnected" Width="190" Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Connected!</Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </GroupBox>
                    </womoc:UcConnection>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Name="gridConnection" MinHeight="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Button Name="btnConnect" Width="55" Margin="100,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsEnabled="False">Connect</Button>
                    <TextBox Name="tbIPAddress" Width="95" Height="18" Margin="0,0,100,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsEnabled="False">10.5.51.130</TextBox>
                    <CheckBox Name="cbMqtt" Width="46" Height="15" Margin="20,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsEnabled="False">Mqtt</CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Name="cbOpc" Width="42" Margin="0,0,20,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsEnabled="False">Opc</CheckBox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </womoc:UcOverviewTabPage>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

UcOverviewTabPage is one of my UserControls, in which there is for example a button. I try to subscribe to the events manually ->

```cs
        public UcOverviewTabPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            cbMqtt.Checked += CbMqtt_Checked;
            cbMqtt.Unchecked += CbMqtt_Unchecked;
            cbOpc.Checked += CbOpc_Checked;
            cbOpc.Unchecked += CbOpc_Unchecked;
            btnConnect.Click += BtnConnect_Click;

            var children = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(this, "btnConnect") as Button;
            bool loaded = children.IsLoaded;
            // -> FALSE
        }
```

Bear in mind, creating new custom UserControls during runtime works perfectly. The problem only occurs when reading out of the XML file.

I except the UserControls or any other Controls to work like they do when created during runtime. What am I missing?

Comment: What are you doing with the `TabItem` after you have loaded it and how is it related to `UcOverviewTabPage`?

Comment: As you can see in the XML file, UcOverviewTabPage is a content of a TabItem. So the problem is probably in the rest of the code?